# How to add a new Kafka topic for every new producer from IoT Hub?

Tags: c#, azure, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, azure-iot-hub

**I'm working on Azure cloud solution. I'm using IoT Hub connected to Kafka in order to process data coming from various IoT devices**. 
What I'm facing is that all the data coming from multiple devices are stored in the same topic . However, I want to process the data of each device connected to IoT Hub to a specific topic in Kafka (Each device has its own Kafka topic)

The Toketi "Kafka Connect Source Connector for Azure IoT Hub" provides the following config file (edge node)

```
connector.class=com.microsoft.azure.iot.kafka.connect.source.IotHubSourceConnector
name=AzureIotHubConnector
tasks.max=1
Kafka.Topic=IotTopic
IotHub.EventHubCompatibleName=iothub-toketi
IotHub.EventHubCompatibleEndpoint=sb://iothub-001.servicebus.windows.net/
IotHub.AccessKeyName=service
IotHub.AccessKeyValue=4KsdfiB9J899a+N3iwerjKwzeqbZUj1K//KKj1ye9i3=
IotHub.ConsumerGroup=$Default
IotHub.Partitions=4
IotHub.StartTime=2016-11-28T00:00:00Z
IotHub.Offsets=
BatchSize=100
ReceiveTimeout=60
```

It workes for one topic to store all data from multiple devices but i expect to do isolation between data coming from devices

Any solutions or ideas !!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One of the solution is to use SMT (Single Message Transformation).

Source Connector flow contains several steps:

- Poll data from external source as `List<SourceRecord>`
- Transform each message (`SourceRecord`) using defined SMT (can be skipped if no Transformation is defined
- Convert key and value of `SourceRecord` to Arrays of bytes.
- Send Message via `KafkaProducer` to Kafka

Kafka Connect determine to which topic send a Message based on `SourceRecord::topic` field. Using SMT you can set proper topic value.

*Pure* Apache Kafka Connect doesn't have such Transformation.
If you are using Confluent Platform some additional Transformation are available.
To extract topic name you can use [ExtractTopic](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html#id1). It has property, that is called `field`

More about whole concept of SMT can be found at [Apache Kafka web page](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) or [Confluent web page](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/index.html)

Comment: i am not working in confluent plateform to use it's options(kafka on Azure) and SMT implentation in Kafka does not respond to my need. Any other solution could be found ??

Comment: @benkhederrami, I think you can download connect-transformations from Confluent and install it in your Kafka Connect (https://www.confluent.io/connector/connect-transformations/). It can be done same way like standard connector. Connectors, Converters and Transformation can be installed as a plugin to Kafka Connect

Comment: How could i extract a name from my message and use it as the topic name then store all messages that contains same name .  I gave him a json message but he mensionned that he can stract field juste from struct message.